# What lot sizes allow Skyscrapers to grow in sim city 4?

Tags: simcity-4

1. Can skyscrapers grow from 5×5 lots on residential or commercial zones?
2. Is there any mod that can build tall skyscrapers on 4×4 or 5×5 lots?
3. Or can enhance textures?
4. Can skyscrapers grow in high density industry zones?

Comment: What do you mean by 'build from'? In SC4 you don't directly build the structures, unless you're referring to buildings you 'plop' down yourself, like landmarks. To get skyscrapers you just mark out the zones and hope that there's sufficient demand and desirability in the area for the buildings to show up.

Comment: I'm presuming 'build from' means growable buildings. Not sure what 'enhance textures' means. If mods can add more lots or buildings, and even more possible lot sizes? Yes, they sure can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that my comment was more of an answer, even though my memory is vague (It's been years since I've played SC4, and I don't currently have a copy.)

I seem to remember there being both 5x5 and 4x4 skyscrapers, but IIRC, the 4x4 were much more common. I do remember that skyscrapers required a huge amount of demand, so that it wasn't easy to get them to spawn. If you're having difficulty, it's probably a demand issue rather than a lot size issue. (Smaller footprint buildings will grow on larger lot sizes, so a 5x5 lot wouldn't prevent a 4x4 skyscraper from spawning on it).

There were no industrial skyscrapers. Only commercial and residential.

For enhanced visuals, you might want to look at modded assets at Simtropolis.com, people have created some fantastic stuff. (I also seem to recall that some mods have been created there which allow skyscrapers to grow more easily, as well)

Comment: The game will build any size lot that's available to it, if you zone that lot size (using CTRL). http://simcity4buildings.net/, click 'stage 8' shows 2x4, 3x3, 3x4, 4x4, and 4x5 lots. Modded buildings can enable more/larger sizes, I believe up to 16x16.